# Disable trace of open files in 3rd party reader in android

Tags: android, filereader

I want to open doc, excel other files in 3rd party readers from application internal memory.

I am successfully read the file from internal memory.

But when you open the google doc or excel reader application,In that in recent tab files are showing and any one can copy that file to external memory.

Is it any possibly to clear the history from 3rd party application. or disable to trace in history.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it any possibly to clear the history from 3rd party application

Only if the application offers some sort of API for this.

> or disable to trace in history.

Only if the application offers some sort of API for this.

You are starting a third-party application. The developers of that application can do whatever they want, and the user can use whatever third-party applications that the user wants.

> In that in recent tab files are showing and any one can copy that file to external memory

Sure. The user might choose an app that immediately uploads the content to a server. It is the user's device. It is the user's apps. And, if the content is on the user's device, it is the user's content. The user can do whatever the user wants with these things.

Comment: but i don't want to give privilege to user for copy the file. M looking for a solution if i copy that file in other temp folder in internal memory and delete once user back to application or stop the application.

Comment: @user3509456: "but i don't want to give privilege to user for copy the file" -- then do not give the content to a third-party app. You will have to implement everything yourself in your own app. "and delete once user back to application or stop the application" -- that will not stop the user from copying the content. The user may be able to do that from within the third-party app, without leaving it. The point of the third-party app that the user chooses may be to copy the content within the app.